# How to store the remaining lines excepted the choosen one?

Tags: c, fgets

In this code, I am trying to skip a line. This means all the lines should be stored in the array except the one that is fetched from entering the id card number.

For example. If I entered the `ID card number` of the first one then this line should be ignored and the remaining lines should be stored in an array. Or if I entered the second one then this second line should be ignored and the remaining lines should be saved in the array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
  char fname[50] = "fiile.csv", toFind[50], str[200];
  FILE * fp1 = fopen(fname, "r+");
  char * line1 = NULL;
  char array[2][200];

  printf("Enter your id card number: ");
  scanf("%s", toFind);

  int count = 0;
  while(fgets(str, 200, fp1)){
    line1 = strtok(str, "\n");
    if(line1){
      count++;
      if(count == 1 && strstr(line1, toFind)){
        strcpy(array[0], line1);
        printf("Here is line %d: %s\n", count, array[0]);
      }
      else if(count == 2 && strstr(line1, toFind)){  
        strcpy(array[1], line1); 
        printf("Here is line %d: %s\n", count, array[1]); 
      }
    } 
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You cannot easily do it this way. Your array only stores two lines at most. You need to use something like `realloc` to hold pointers to the lines, and allocate memory for those with `malloc` as well.

Comment: @Barmar I updated the code by removing array from `count`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare the array with as many elements you need to be able to store (if you don't know the maximum, you'll need to use dynamic allocation with `malloc()` and `realloc()`, but I'm not going to show that in this answer.

Then use an index variable to hold the current position that you're saving to, which you don't increment when you skip a line. Use this index variable when copying, rather than hard-coding every index.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXLINES 1000

int main(){
    char fname[50] = "file.csv", toFind[50], str[200], array[MAXLINES][200];
    FILE * fp1 = fopen(fname, "r+");
    char * line1 = NULL;

    printf("Enter your id card number: ");
    scanf("%s", toFind);

    int index = 0;
    while(index < MAXLINES && fgets(str, 200, fp1)){
        line1 = strtok(str, "\n");
        if(line1)
        {
            if (!strstr(line1, toFind)) {
                strcpy(array[index], line1);
                printf("Here is line %d: %s\n", index, line1);
                index++;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```